# How to make tightvnc listen for incoming connections on port 5900?

Tags: networking, configuration, vnc, tightvnc

I'm running tightvnc on a raspberry pi and looking at the log

```
/root/.vnc/hostname:5900.log
```

I see this line:

```
30/04/14 09:23:18 Listening for VNC connections on TCP port 11800
```

How can I change this so it listens on port 5900?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tehehe, you got the schema behind the command line wrong.  The argument you give to `tightvnc` is the *display* number, not *port* number.  Display numbers correspond to port numbers in the way that

```
port = display + 5900
```

So display `0` would result in port 5900, display `5900` in port 11800.  Took me a while, too. ;)